# Is the Roundtrip tag of value?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The [roundtrip](/questions/tagged/roundtrip) tag seems to be very undefined in what it is used for.  What should be done about it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, burn it.

It could mean anything, from as http to a database roundtrip. From a network roundtrip to a question about Android and GPS.